# Is there a way to attach a pager control to a dynamicViewPanel from the extension library?

Tags: lotus-domino, pager, xpages

I'm Using 8.5.3 UP1 and I really like the extension libraries dynamicViewPanel but I am at a loss as to how I would attach a pager control to it? It would seem like it should be something obvious but I can't figure it out.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seem to work if you use the standard pager, but I could not get it to work using the pager Add Row control in extlib. maybe you should report this to the extlib team at openntf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
<xe:dynamicViewPanel id="dynamicViewPanel1" showCheckbox="true"
    showHeaderCheckbox="true" showColumnHeader="true"
    showUnreadMarks="true" rows="5">
    <xe:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="View"></xp:dominoView>
    </xe:this.data>
</xe:dynamicViewPanel>
<xp:pager layout="Previous Group Next" partialRefresh="true"
    id="pager1" for="dynamicViewPanel1">
</xp:pager>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly!! I was just confused since I couldn't select the viewpanel from the Attach To in the properties of the pager. Never even thought about just typing for="dynamicViewPanel1"!